# How to hide some networks from appearing in “Available Wi-Fi networks” dialog?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

When I open the ***Network status*** tab I see the following option:

[image]

Pressing on it open all available ***Wi-Fi*** networks around:

[image]

**Is it possible to prevent some networks from appearing in this “Available Wi-Fi networks” dialog?**

Thanks

Comment: Your title is very misleading: based on the accepted answer you don't want to hide Windows from the networks but hide the networks from Windows, that is just the opposite...

Comment: @Robert: I think, in my case networks are hidden because of the Windows block access for defined network(s). Or you suppose that the networks will not be shown in my system, but they will be able to connect to my computer and use its resources?

Comment: Networks do not connect to your computer. Your computer initiates the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make Windows 10 to be hidden for some
> networks/interfaces and prevent some interfaces from appearing in this
> dialog?

You can use:

`netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WIFI_NAME" networktype=infrastructure`

to remove specific SSIDs.

Over time however, new points keep popping up.  I have learned to simply ignore the access points.

That works better for me.

**Followup (to address additional issues raised:**

`netsh` and `netsh wlan` have numerous options.  Run `netsh wlan /?`  to see the options available.

So if you wanted to get a list of wireless profile you are using run:

`netsh wlan show profiles`.

You can get a list of all the access points your Windows machine sees by running:

`netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid`
(courtesy of members posts on this issue)

Finally you can use netsh commands in a batch file.

Comment: It's great! Thanks! Possible can you advice how to list all _ssid_ to be able save to a text file? I want to write some application to analyze from time to time all _ssid_ and keep only predefined.

Comment: Yes.  you can use netsh wlan show profiles .  I added some information to my answer. This are profiles you are using. You need a scanner for points you have not used.

Comment: I analyzed information used `netsh wlan show profiles` and found that it doesn't show all networks/interfaces appearing in the “Available Wi-Fi networks” dialog. For example, in my case `netsh wlan show profiles` prints me 4 profiles, but actually I have more than 20 Wi-Fi connections. I tried `netsh wlan show networks` too. But this command shows only one network.

Comment: I added the information related to ..... mode=bssid in my answer and this is all working (allowing for an instant in time).